# How to highlight Bootstrap parent table row by finding keyword in collapsed row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, domparser

I would like to highlight normal title table row in Bootstrap if normal table row or "child" collapsed table row contains at least 1 keyword from array.

Let's say that I have an array of keywords. 2., 4., 6. table row are collapsed in Bootstrap, they are children of their parent (not in sense of DOM). 1. `<tr>` contains keyword1 in title. 4. collapsed table row contains also keyword2.

So far I managed to make this partially chubby-workable solution. Problem is that when collapsed table row contains keyword it does not highlight "parent" row.

Working example: http://www.bootply.com/WYvFXheQlN

JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("tr:contains(keyword1)" ).addClass("yellow");
   $("tr:contains(keyword2)" ).addClass("yellow");
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a>Title1 keyword1 ...</a>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Open</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" id="collapse1">
          <td colspan="2">
            ...lorem ipsum ...
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a>Title2 ...</a>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Open</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" id="collapse2">
          <td colspan="2">
            .... keyword2 lorem ipsum ...
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a>Title3</a>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Open</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" id="collapse3">
          <td colspan="2">
            ... lorem ipsum ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

So naturally I tried different variations playing with DOM and jQuery. Puting child row into parent row seems as good idea. I tried to use jQuery's functions parent(),parents() or closest() but still, neither solution was taking correct table row and highlighted it.

*Following code also works but never highlight parent `<tr>`:*

```
       <tr>
          <td>
            <a>Title2 ...</a>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Open</a>
          </td>
          <tr class="collapse" id="collapse2">
             <td colspan="2">
               ...lorem ipsum keyword2...
             </td>
          </tr>
        </tr>
```

Can anybody help me? **How to highlight parent table row when keyword is in child table row content?**

p.s.bonus: This was the first code I settled. Keywords are in string, code highlight only keyword itself.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regex = /('keyword1|keyword2|...')/g;
    $(\'tbody\').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();
        if (regex.test(text)) {
            $this.html( $this.html().replace(regex, \'<span class="yellow">$1</span>\') );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```